# p:poll does not seem to do anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using a `<p:poll>` as follows:

```
<p:poll listener="#{realBean.reload()}" interval="60" update="marche"/>

<p:dataList type="inset" id="mydatalist" style="width: 100%; font-size: 9px;" value="#{realBean.listMarketValues}" var="list">
    <f:facet name="header">
    </f:facet>
</p:dataList>
```

However, it doesn't seem to do anything. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: In the future, whenever you stumble upon a possible JS related problem, please look in browser's JS console for clues and post them in the question if they are not understood. You can get the console by pressing F12 in Chrome/IE>=9/Firefox/Firebug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe , you forgot to give interval attribute of poll tag.
It should be

`<p:poll interval="60" listener="#{realMarketBean.rechargerLeMarcheTempsreel()}" update="marche"/>`

interval 60 means 60 seconds.
HTH,
Thanks

Comment: thinks Pankaj Kathiriya
although I added the attribute does not work !
i find a javaScript solution

Comment: which version of primefaces are you using? and what javascript solution you found? Ideally interval attribute should work.